# Datagrid to Excel in ASP.NET C# - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I recently started to code in [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010) from Visual Studio 2005. I need code to export to [Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) from a datagrid. In Visual Studio 2005 the following code was used.

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=dgd.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
    dgd.Visible = true;
    dgd.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    Response.End();
```

This does not yield the same result in Visual Studio 2005. The header is not aligned to the column. The pictures in the datagrid are not fetched in Excel, and the links in the datagrid do not appear properly. What would be better code?

Answer (score 0):

```
Add following code after htmlwriter line


`if (dtDetails.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < gvProduction.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    gvProduction.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-color", "#507CD1");
                }
                int j = 1;
                //This loop is used to apply stlye to cells based on particular row
                foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvProduction.Rows)
                {
                    gvrow.BackColor = Color.White;
                    if (j <= gvProduction.Rows.Count)
                    {
                        if (j % 2 != 0)
                        {
                            for (int k = 0; k < gvrow.Cells.Count; k++)
                            {
                                gvrow.Cells[k].Style.Add("background-color", "#EFF3FB");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                gvProduction.RenderControl(hw);
                Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.End();
            }`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code.

On the export button click:

```
FileInfo FI = new FileInfo(Path);
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
DataGrid DataGrd = new DataGrid();
DataGrd.DataSource = dt1;
DataGrd.DataBind();

DataGrd.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
string directory = Path.Substring(0, Path.LastIndexOf("\\")); // GetDirectory(Path);
if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
}

System.IO.StreamWriter vw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Path, true);
stringWriter.ToString().Normalize();
vw.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
vw.Flush();
vw.Close();
WriteAttachment(FI.Name, "application/vnd.ms-excel", stringWriter.ToString());
```

Code for writing attachment:

```
public static void WriteAttachment(string FileName, string FileType, string content)
{
   HttpResponse Response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
   Response.ClearHeaders();
   Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
   Response.ContentType = FileType;
   Response.Write(content);
   Response.End();
}
```

For more references, see *[Export Gridview Data to Excel in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/477436/Export-Gridview-Data-to-Excel-in-ASP-NET)*.

Answer (score 0):

The below code may help you to write an Excel sheet using gridview.

```
// Function to export datagridview to excel sheet
// excel_file contains the path to the excel file.
public void export_to_excel(DataGridView dgv, string excel_file)
{
    int cols;

    //Open file
    StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(excel_file);

    //Determine the number of columns and write columns to file
    cols = dgv.Columns.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        wr.Write(dgv.Columns[i].HeaderText.ToString().ToUpper() + "\t");
    }
    wr.WriteLine();

    //Write rows to the Excel file
    for (int i = 0; i < (dgv.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            if (dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
                wr.Write(dgv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value + "\t");
            else
            {
                wr.Write("\t");
            }
        }
        wr.WriteLine();
    }

    //Close file
    wr.Close();
}
```

Also, you can go through the blog post *[How to Export Data to Excel from an ASP.NET Application + Avoid the File Format Differ Prompt](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erikaehrli/archive/2009/01/30/how-to-export-data-to-excel-from-an-asp-net-application-avoid-the-file-format-differ-prompt.aspx)*.

Answer (score 0):

I am using same in our project.

```
 private void ExportToExcel(DataTable dt)
    {
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string filename = "DownloadReport.xls";
            System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
            DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
            dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
            dgGrid.DataBind();

            //Get the HTML for the control.
            dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
            //Write the HTML back to the browser.
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
            this.EnableViewState = false;
            Response.Write(tw.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps you